# Is it possible to have ActionFilter exceptions handled via the [HandleError] mechanism?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception, action-filter, handleerror

I have a custom action filter (AuthenticateAttribute) in my ASP.NET MVC 3 application that ensures that users are logged in.

I want to raise exceptions in the OnActionExecuting method and would like those to be handled by the HandleError global filter. Is that possible and, if so, how do I do it?

Currently, raising an exception in OnActionExecuting bypasses the HandleError global filter - presumably because that only traps exceptions that occur within the action iself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions thrown in the `OnActionExecuting` will be handled by the global `HandleErrorAttribute`. You just need to ensure that in your web.config you have enabled it:

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

This being said you talked about an `AuthenticateAttribute` and the `OnActionExecuting` event. Those two notions are incompatible. If you are writing a custom authorization attribute you should be probably deriving from `AuthorizeAttribute` and overriding the `AuthorizeCore` method for the authentication and the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method for handling the unauthorized case.

You also have the possibility if you don't want to use the global `HandleErrorAttribute` to do the following instead of throwing exceptions:

```
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
{
    ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/401.cshtml"
};
```

Setting a result inside an action attribute will short-circuit the execution of the controller action and directly render the view.

Comment: Hmmm... It seems that the HandleErrors mechanism only works for certain types of exception. I was throwing UnauthorizedAccessException, which wasn't being caught. But Exception *is* handled as expected.

Comment: Yeah, custom unhandled UnauthorizedExceptions within your controller logic will not be handled by the asp.net pipleine (and ridirect to CustomErrors). Consider creating a ExceptionAttribute implementing IExceptionFilter, and then register it in GlobalFilters. Within this, you could re-throw the custom exception as a HttpException(401), with the custom exception as an inner.  That would make the asp.net pipeline pick it up and use the pages defined in CustomErrors.